# Disable copying and pasting of files while running program

Tags: c#

I was wondering if it was possible to disable users copying and pasting an external file while running my C# application?

example user runs application while it is running clipboard cannot be used, when the application is finished it then enables the clipboard again user can copy and paste now.

I found this [prevent-cut-paste-copy-delete-re-naming-of-files-folders](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/prevent-cut-paste-copy-delete-re-naming-of-files-folders)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What _on earth_ for?

Comment: +1 for the previous comment. And not just for the rhetorical bit.

Comment: XY Problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Making a launcher for a game and I want to make sure user don't copy temp files while they are running the game.

Comment: Maybe you can encrypt the temp files instead?

Comment: You can't stop people from doing that.  Anything your program can read, another program can also read.  Your only hope is a dedicated hardware key.

Comment: Can't encrypt unfortunately as the game is reading these temp files.

Comment: Yes, once you've disabled the clipboard no hacker on the planet will be able to copy those files. Well, not unless they have heard of CopyFile.

Comment: Don't do this. Even if your app is a fullscreen game, it is not the only app running. Don't take control of the user's computer. What if they want to alt-tab and do something else for a while?

Comment: @slaks they offer no protection either!

Comment: @user1170297, (deserves -1 for asking question unrelated to what you actually want to do, but...) you should think about what you are trying to prevent and edit the question - disabling/altering copy/paste is pretty much guaranteed way for your program to never be used.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: That's not true.  As long as the content never leaves the device, it is possible to build secure hardware.

Comment: @slaks in this case it's not much use on the device

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: That depends on what the files are used for.  He could also give the device its own HDCP-enabled video output (although that would be massive overkill)

Answer (score 1):

Answer to: "The user runs my launcher this runs the game and then connects to server where they download a file, this file is stored in a appdata this is the file i dont want people to copy".

The only option to prevent user from copying file on its own computer is to not send file there in a first place.

If you just want merely discourage people from copying the file (as it would be the case of "disable copy/paste") then opening file as non-sharable, delete-on-close may be enough.

Comment: Yea I have to send them the file unfortunately for the game, but you get the occasional editor who wants to have a poke around :/ not ideal when your making a MMORPG I guess delete-on-close may be my only option

Comment: Don't forget that streaming your own response to your request may be easier then hacking with file on disk. At any rate - if user receives information it is already there - decide what and how much you want to protect and spend your resources accordingly. It actually may be beneficial if people "poke around" - meaning they actually play your game.

Answer (score 0):

Very difficult, if not impossible, and most likely totally unnecessary - what you have in plan. Clipboard belongs to the OS, and not just to your application. Think about how to solve the root of your problem in another way. If you explain what you're trying to do, maybe somebody will suggest how they would solve that particular problem. Why are you using the clipboard to maintain user/application state? If you accept input that way, then copy that data into your application's memory (or elsewhere), then work with it. Don't expect it to stay in the clipboard until your app is done working with it. However, also note that, it'd be against all usability rules to update/change the content of the clipboard with the result of that calculation - if that's what your mind is going as you're reading this.

Comment: It is possible to disable the clipboard; however, I won't give any detail.

Comment: It is actually relatively easy to break copy/paste... but hopefully it is not what OP wants.

Comment: If stoping copy and paste isnt an option what do you recomend then?more info: The user runs my launcher this runs the game and then connects to server where they download a file, this file is stored in a appdata this is the file i dont want people to copy.

encrypting it is not possible as the game needs to read it and after they close the game it gets deleted. im not trying to make something "hack proof" just a deterrent for your every day bloke.

Comment: how big is the file? do you really need to store it to the disk? keep it in app's memory, and use it from there. it's binary data; it must be possible. well, unless it's huge, in which case, I'd probably scramble/encrypt it somehow (if you really want to make it useless to the user). plus, disabling the clipboard won't make it impossible for them to copy it to another drive by dragging it there, not to mention using other tools or cmd prompt.

Comment: The file is only 2 - 5mb but i dont think it is possible to not have a hard drive copy of the file "Hard Coded into game"

Comment: Embedded-file-in-assembly is definitely an option at under 10mb.

Comment: If you're saying that you can't control (change code) that reads the content of that file, then dropping the file to the disk is your only option. However, I still cannot be convinced that there's a good reason that the user shouldn't be able to view or make a copy of that file. I honestly don't have any other suggestions; sorry. edit: I mean, disabling the clipboard, aside from being bad from usability standpoint, will not stop a dedicated user to copy that file w/o the use of clipboard (drag to another drive, use cmd-prompt to copy it, another tool to open, save somewhere, or copy somewhere)

Comment: Correct I don't have any control of that. I know im going to have find an ugly way around this, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

That would be plain evil. Whatever the purpose. Remember, whenever you get to a task that need you to do some hacks just to provide a workaround to avoid dealing with some security layer being there with a reason or (as in your case) messing with some low-level operating system functionalities to change their bahavior, ask yourself if it even makes any sense.

You either don't need that feature, or you are searching for a security issue in the system/software which will be fixed within weeks or months.

You may actually implement some ugly non-reliable obstacles preventing the user to do those operations, but the user will always be able to find a different way to do them. Except if you are dealing with some DRM stuff, which I doubt.

And however, preventing the user to copy-paste? That definitely won't be some happy user ...

Answer (score 0):

If you were going to download the file on every execution anyway, then you could download it at the game's "loading screen" and keep it in an in-memory stream. Less evil than having to hook the clipboard, and pulling it out involves debuggers or the ability to extract from the swapfile...

I'm not a fan of this solution (and I suspect you/you client will not be either) due to the bandwidth costs of downloading the core data of the game at every launch...